# R Dynamically Assiging a Flag Using a CrossWalk to Identify Groups of Percentiles

Tags: r

I have the following datasets (df & crs_walk):

```
 start <- as.POSIXct("2020-01-01")
 interval <- 60*60
 end <- as.POSIXct("2020-03-31")
 date_col <- seq(from=start, by=interval, to=end)

 num_col <- runif(length(date_col), 100, 1000)

 df <- bind_cols(date_col, num_col)
 colnames(df)[1] <- "Date"
 colnames(df)[2] <- "Value"

 x <- c("Win1", "Win2", "Win3", "Win4")
 y <- c(40, 1005, 450, 665)
 pct <- c(.018519, .465278, .208333, .30787)

 crs_walk <- cbind(x,y,pct)
```

I would like to assign the name "Win1", "Win2", "Win3", or "Win4" to a new column in `df` based on the following rules.  If the `Value` in `df` is in the top 1.8519% or the top 40 values (as detailed in `crs_walk`) I would like to label it "Win1". If the `Value` is in the next set of 1005 values or in the top 46.5%, I would like to label it "Win2", and so on.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach:

```
library(dplyr)

arrange(df, Value) %>%
  mutate(x = rep(crs_walk[, "x"], as.integer(crs_walk[, "y"])))
```

Returns:

```
# A tibble: 2,160 x 3
   Date                Value x    
   <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>
 1 2020-01-01 12:00:00  100. Win1 
 2 2020-03-09 06:00:00  100. Win1 
 3 2020-02-08 22:00:00  101. Win1 
 4 2020-02-11 02:00:00  101. Win1 
 5 2020-03-17 03:00:00  101. Win1 
 6 2020-02-04 14:00:00  101. Win1 
 7 2020-03-03 11:00:00  102. Win1 
 8 2020-02-09 06:00:00  102. Win1 
 9 2020-03-14 04:00:00  102. Win1 
10 2020-02-02 11:00:00  102. Win1 
# … with 2,150 more rows
```

Comment: Thank You!  Would this also work if x what a character and y was numeric? I am receiving errors and I don't entirely know how this process is working.  In my actual data, I am using a vector rather than a list.

Comment: Yes, in fact my code coerces y to numeric, so numeric y will not be a problem. Feel free to post a sample in your actual format.